# Symfony fetch/persist entity-oriented service naming conventions and best practice

Tags: symfony, naming-conventions, entitymanager

A Symfony2 application typically has a collection of entities. A Doctrine `EntityManager` is commonly used to fetch and persist these entities.

Entities are used in multiple places throughout the application; for many entities, and per entity, it makes sense to wrap up the handling of a given entity plus fetching/persisting in a service.

For example, for a `User` entity there may be a `UserService` with `fetchUser($user_id)` and `persistUser(User $user)` methods (or maybe just `fetch()` and `persist(`) methods, this is an example only).

An application can end up with many entity-oriented services for the fetching and persisting of entities. Such services will be similar in their interfaces, differing in the type of entity handled.

That an application can contain many entity-oriented services seems a common situation. It follows that the matter of naming and architecting such services is a common problem.

For a new application to require the creation of, for example, a base `EntityService` and child `UserService`, `WidgetService` and `ProductService` classes feels repetitive, as in the means for dealing with such aspects should be a solved problem.

- **Are there best practices for introducing such entity-management related services into a Symfony application?**

  This feels like it should be a solved problem, with perhaps a well-trod design pattern to follow.
- **Are there naming conventions that would be advisable to follow?**

  I've observed, in different applications, both `UserManager` and `UserService` chosen as service names. Are there prevailing conventions?

Comment: Since i've a similar question, and since for find an answer I "mine" myself some well-known bundles, i tell you that "Manager" naming convention SEEMS TO BE preferred to "Service" naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

As for the naming, there are no conventions that I know of for such situations, but there is the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` class which manages entity, so I would use `Manager` instead of `Service`.

Now, talking about entity management services: do you really need so many services? If the `UserService::persistUser()` method does nothing more than just persisting the user, why are you using a custom service and not the default `EntityManager`?

Also, you shouldn't put repository and persisting methods all together in the same class. Isn't it easier to use a custom repository for the entity?